# Ant compiles but doesn't create the classes

Tags: java, ant

Ok, sorry if it is repeated, but I promise I googled it, searched around forums and similar.

The thing is, I have to compile a big java project to create a war file. The problem is, it depends on a lot of classes and jars that I own.

So, I started building the project from command line, everything goes right, but when I tried to apply the same with ant, ant doesn't create the classes... or directories... or anything. It says that the compilation was successful but the output directory does not have any classes.

So, here's part of my partial **build.xml**, at least, the important part for me.

```
<target name="we">
    <javac destdir="${proj.name}/${comp.res}">
        <src path="${proj.name}/cnt.web/${proj.version}/exception" />
        <src path="${proj.name}/cnt.web/${proj.version}/base" />
        <src path="${proj.name}/cnt.web/${proj.version}/core" />
        <classpath refid="my.path"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```

I've tried with lots of combinations, from *srcdir* to this aproach. Nothing seems to work when I do:

```
ant we
```

It says that it's successful, that it registered *n* files to compile, and that's all, the resulting directories and classes aren't where they are suposed to be. I tried reading the debug and verbose but nothing seems to be wrong.

Any ideas could help.

Comment: did you try running ant with the verbose command line option?

Comment: If you add `<echo message="${proj.name}/${comp.res}" />`, do you obtain the destination dir you are expecting?

Comment: can you post your ant log which shows it picks up the src from the above path?

Comment: I've tried running with verbose and nothing special to work around.
With the echo I see the expected destiny.
I'll try another things and post the log after that.

Comment: Did you declare the property `comp.res`, and does it get declared before the target you posted is run?  If not, the .class files will land in a directory named (literally) `${comp.res}`.

Comment: Yes, I declared all my properties at the start of my build.xml and, no, there isn't any folder called as the same as my property. (I actually checked this as my first mistake but, no, it wasn't)

Comment: Use <javac destdir="${proj.name}/${comp.res}" failonerror="true"> as failonerror=false is <javac> default, so it will always print BUILD SUCCESSFUL ! also for testing whether your properties are set correctly 'decorate' your <javac ... /> part with a surrounding <echoxml> ... your <javac .../> goes here </echoxml> and you'll see how they are resolved